# Reading DigitalProductId from registry comes back null

Tags: c#, null, registry

I'm Currently trying to get my Product key of my windows 7 installation from the registry. but for some reason DigitalProductId is coming back null. And I can't figure out why it's doing that.

I can read other values in the "NT\Current Version" just fine. like "productName" but when it comes to the digitalProductId I'm getting nothing.

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Collections;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] results = Form1.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(Form1.Key.Windows);
            string cdKey = Form1.DecodeProductKey(results);
            MessageBox.Show(cdKey, "HWID()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }


        public enum Key { Windows };
        public static byte[] GetRegistryDigitalProductId(Key key)
        {
            byte[] digitalProductId = null;
            RegistryKey registry = null;
            switch (key)
            {
                case Key.Windows:
                    registry =
                      Registry.LocalMachine.
                        OpenSubKey(
                          @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion",
                            false);
                    break;
            }
            if (registry != null)
            {
                digitalProductId = registry.GetValue("DigitalProductId")
                  as byte[];
                registry.Close();
            }
            return digitalProductId;
        }
        public static string DecodeProductKey(byte[] digitalProductId)
        {
            const int keyStartIndex = 52;
            const int keyEndIndex = keyStartIndex + 15;
            char[] digits = new char[]
     {
       'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 
       'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9',
     };
            const int decodeLength = 29;
            const int decodeStringLength = 15;
            char[] decodedChars = new char[decodeLength];
            ArrayList hexPid = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = keyStartIndex; i <= keyEndIndex; i++)
            {
                hexPid.Add(digitalProductId[i]);
            }
            for (int i = decodeLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if ((i + 1) % 6 == 0)
                {
                    decodedChars[i] = '-';
                }
                else
                {
                    int digitMapIndex = 0;
                    for (int j = decodeStringLength - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        int byteValue = (digitMapIndex << 8) | (byte)hexPid[j];
                        hexPid[j] = (byte)(byteValue / 24);
                        digitMapIndex = byteValue % 24;
                        decodedChars[i] = digits[digitMapIndex];
                    }
                }
            }
            return new string(decodedChars);
        }

    }
}
```

I'm new to c# and I'm trying to follow this guide. 
http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2013/05/how-to-get-windows-product-key-in-c.html

But I'm having trouble getting to work correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your code as-is if you target 64-bit in your build.

---

Otherwise, you get directed here, and you might not find the key you're looking for:

> SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\...

So use this code if you have to target 32-bit:

```
var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

var reg = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", false);

var digitalProductId = reg.GetValue("DigitalProductId") as byte[];
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, and yes my build is a 64 bit. But, when I went to "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" in regedit there was no DigitalProductId listed... (maybe I'm not fully understanding what you are saying) Also, if you were to rewrite the switch(key) to work correctly what would it look like? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Never mind. After playing around with your code, I was able to understand what you are saying. and I got it to work correctly. Thanks for the help. Now I understand what you have to do for each build.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string getKey(string from = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", string valueName = "DigitalProductId")
{
            RegistryKey hive = null;
            RegistryKey key = null;
            try
            {
                var result = string.Empty;
                hive = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Environment.MachineName);
                key = hive.OpenSubKey(from, false);
                var k = RegistryValueKind.Unknown;
                try { k = key.GetValueKind(valueName); }
                catch (Exception) { }

                if (k == RegistryValueKind.Unknown)
                {
                    key.Close();
                    hive.Close();
                    hive = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
                    key = hive.OpenSubKey(from, false);
                    try { k = key.GetValueKind(valueName); }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                }

                if (k == RegistryValueKind.Binary)
                {
                    var pivot = 0;
                    var bytes = (byte[])key.GetValue(valueName);
                    var ints = new int[16];
                    for (var i = 52; i < 67; ++i) ints[i - 52] = bytes[i];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
                    {
                        pivot = 0;
                        for (var j = 14; j >= 0; --j)
                        {
                            pivot <<= 8;
                            pivot ^= ints[j];
                            ints[j] = ((int)Math.Truncate(pivot / 24.0));
                            pivot %= 24;
                        }
                        result = possible_chars[pivot] + result;
                        if ((i % 5 == 4) && (i != 24))
                        {
                            result = "-" + result;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception) { return null; }
            finally
            {
                 key?.Close();
                 hive?.Close();
            }
}
private static readonly string possible_chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789";
```